# Getting error while tryin to create database from my C# application

Tags: windows, oracle, data-access-layer

"Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "DbDalFactory_ISuborderSplitInclusionProvider"?"

Already tried adding this key to the config file, also checked oracle.DataAccess versions referred in solution.

Comment: The error got resolved by installing the 32bit client for oracle, I was using 64 bit client earlier with a 32 bit provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error got resolved by installing the 32bit client for oracle, I was using 64 bit client earlier with a 32 bit provider, the client and provider should be same while creating database connections.